# Move a list from a frame to another frame

Tags: java, list, awt

In this code, I need to display a list of drugs formed by selected items from another 3 lists from another class  and I want to show in my frame in this class I create a object 'c' from where I initialised my list.

I put selected items into "items" and then i move items in a `java.awt.List mylist`
but when I run code, don't show anything about my list.

If for example I make `items = c.getList_drugs_critics()` and I display it right, show the correct list, but if I want too show selected items from 3 lists don t run.

Comment: dimension= getLista_medicamente_critice().getSelectedIndexes().length + c.getLista_medicamente_raceala().getSelectedIndexes().length+c.getLista_medicamente_uzuale().getSelectedIndexes().length;
        items = c.getList_drugs_critics().getSelectedItems();
        items = c.getList_drugs_cold().getSelectedItems();
        items = c.getList_drugs_usualy().getSelectedItems(;
        
        for(int i = 0 ;i < dimOfList;i++)
        {
            mylist.add(items[i]);
        }
        
        p.add(mylist);

Comment: Put that code in the question with formatting.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)